# VBA Selenium : How to extract the text data in the unmerged form..as in like Spec1 : Value1 | Spec2 : Value2 | Spec3 : Value3...etc

Tags: vba, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9PgP.png)I was trying to extract some data part from the list of webpage links that I have in my excel sheet and with the help of the below code, I could able to extract the data, but the problem is.. the result data that I am getting is in merged form... like this "ColorOrangeMaterialPolyethyleneDimensions6 x 37 inFor Use With(1 to 3) 36 in Blankets...." This is the link of the data.. FYI "https://www.grainger.com/product/SALISBURY-Blanket-Canister-Orange-3KUX9". Any suggestions on how to export the data in the form of like(Spec1:Value1|Spec2:Value2... Like this)would be greatly appreciated. Please advise.

This is the code..

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ResultSections As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim ResultSection As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        
        Dim MyUrl As String
        MyUrl = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        Set MB = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
        
        MB.Start
        MB.Get MyUrl
        MB.Wait 10000
        
        Set ResultSections = MB.FindElementsByClass("P9I57X")
        
        For Each ResultSection In ResultSections
            Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = ResultSection.Text
            Exit For
        Next ResultSection
        
        If i = lastrow Then
            MB.Quit
        End If
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

Kindly help me out with this..:-)

I tried to extract the data part of a webpage link, but it is coming the merged form and I couldn't able to differentiate which is the label name and which is the value. So I need that extracted data to be in the right format. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

Select for the dt and dd elements rather than a parent. That way you can set two lists to iterate over and access the desired content and the level where text is as appears on screen. Select a single element, as you are, higher up the DOM and you get this mangled looking string.

Code below should get you started. Note you also don't need to keep creating a new webDriver instance inside your loop.

```
Dim specs As Selenium.WebElements, values As Selenium.WebElements, i As Long

Set specs = MB.FindElementsByCss("[data-testid='product-techs'] dt")
Set values = MB.FindElementsByCss("[data-testid='product-techs'] dd")

For i = 1 To specs.Count
     Debug.Print Join$(Array(specs.Item(i).Text, values.Item(i).Text), ":")
Next
```

Comment: Many thanks, @QHarr. It was of great help. I'm able to use the code you provided for the purpose I needed, it worked only with single web page link, but my requirement in here is, it has to work for multiple links all at once in the right manner. I tried the code below for that, however it only listed only one specification, not all the specs, in the result page. What can be fixed with the following code. Kindly advise.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9PgP.png

Comment: Set specs = MB.FindElementsByCss("[data-testid='product-techs'] dt")
  Set values = MB.FindElementsByCss("[data-testid='product-techs'] dd")
  For j = 1 To specs.Count
  Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
  Next............................................                                                                                                                                       With this code, it is extracting, only the last "attribute label & value" that is there in the list, but i need all the labels & values. Please advise.